# App Script slow with many calls the same function that has several ranges which it calls getValues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

I converted a complex formula in google spreadsheet into a custom function that simplifies readability and tweaking of the algorithm. However, the function call is a lot slower than the spreadsheet formula. I think its because I have several getValues calls that pull in few lookup tables. Since I call this function 1000+ times, that ends up being a lot of getValues on the same ranges. These lookup table occasionally get modified but largely are static.

In Excel, you can have load these values into global variables on file opening and update as needed with a subroutine call (and a spreadsheet button). Any way to do this in Google Apps Script?

Comment: custom functions are pretty slow. How often do you need it to be live calculating? It might make more sense to have it calculate every cell on the coding side every hour or ten minutes or when you open the spreadsheet rather than using custom functions.

Comment: See [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Do not insert the custom function in 1000 formulas, but modify the custom function so that it accepts a range of 1000 rows and returns 1000 results, with one call. See [custom function optimization tips](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization).

Alternatively, implement your slow spreadsheet formulas as array formulas that do the same thing — one formula filling a whole column or range in one go. An array enabled formula can use ranges and [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). These Google Sheet functions accept and/or return arrays of results, even without an `arrayformula()` wrapper: `filter()`, `sort()`, `sortn()`, `index()`, `query()`, `unique()`, `transpose()`, `indirect()`, `offset()`, `flatten()`, `split()`, `mmult()`, `iferror()`, `ifna()`, `switch()`, `choose()`, `isbetween()`, `importrange()`,  `array_constrain()`, `frequency()`, `growth()`, `linest()`, `logest()`, `minverse()`, `trend()`, `daverage()`, `dcount()`, `dcounta()`, `dget()`, `dmax()`, `dmin()`, `dproduct()`, `dstdev()`, `dstdevp()`, `dsum()`, `dvar()` or `dvarp()`.